# How to a add box inside the div with different background color?

Tags: css

My scenario here:

Inside the div which is mentioned below I need to add Find Out More link in right bottom of the div which should contain different bg-color in other words a box structure with an arrow image at the last.

```
.answerbox
{
height: 150px; /*Specify Height*/
width:  150px; /*Specify Width*/
border: 1px solid black; /*Add 1px solid border, use any color you want*/
background-color: green; /*Add a background color to the box*/
text-align:center; /*Align the text to the center*/
}
```

How It should look :

[image]

Comment: What? Can you rephrase the question a bit?

Comment: Do you want the "Find Out More" link to be on a separate line or appended to the end of the pre-existing content?

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Kindly see the picture.. Hope you can understand now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this? Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puVpg/2/)

By setting the parent (`.answerbox`) to `position: relative`, I'm able to set `.more` to `position:absolute` and position it wherever I like in that box; In this case, bottom right of the container.

**HTML**

```
<div class="answerbox">
    <a href="#" class="more">Find out more</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.answerbox {
    height: 150px; /*Specify Height*/
    width:  150px; /*Specify Width*/
    border: 1px solid black; /*Add 1px solid border, use any color you want*/
    background-color: green; /*Add a background color to the box*/
    text-align:center; /*Align the text to the center*/
    position: relative;
}
.more {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

#### Edit - In case you want an arrow image on the button

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puVpg/4/)

**CSS**

```
.more {
    background: url('http://dc390.4shared.com/img/AgV87Tvx/s7/arrow_small_right.png') no-repeat left center red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 20px; /* Extra padding left to make room for the button */
    line-height: 30px; /* Used to center the text vertically. Use the same value as the height.*/
}
```

#### Edit - Let the box grow with the content

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puVpg/5/)

**CSS**

```
.answerbox {
    width:  150px; /*Specify Width*/
    border: 1px solid black; /*Add 1px solid border, use any color you want*/
    background-color: green; /*Add a background color to the box*/
    text-align:center; /*Align the text to the center*/
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 10px 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you mean something like this:

```
<div class="answerbox">
    <a href='#' class="findout">
        find out more..
    </a>
</div>
```

and

```
.findout
{
    position:relative;
    top:120px;
    left:20px;
    background-color:white;
    color:Red;
}
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwXtE/)